# Multiple background images on body tag not scaling properly in CSS

Tags: css, image, background

I'm making a basic website mock-up on HTML, and I can't seem to scale two images separately. This just ends up with Both images scaling down to 70% instead of the first one:

```
.banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("GlassEffect.png"), linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.20),rgba(0,0,0,0.90)), url("background.jpg");
    background-size: 70%, cover;
    background-position: center, top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

Tried changing the first few values separately but that made it even worse, am I mistaken in assuming that my background-size is correctly formatted for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You assigned 3 properties to the background-image but only used 2 further in your code.

```
.banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("GlassEffect.png"), linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.20),rgba(0,0,0,0.90)), url("background.jpg");
    background-size: 70%, cover,cover;
    background-position: center, top,top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat,no-repeat;
}
```

Your linear gradient is currently stacked above the second picture. Maybe you should also change the hierarchy.

Comment: Oh god, thanks for the reply. For some reason after adding the second image I was treating the last two properties as one.